# In a transmission line, does the real current interact with reactive impedances?

Tags: transmission-line, power-engineering, reactive-power, power-generation, distribution-network

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1T2Si.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

According to the diagram above, if *real* currents do not interact with *reactive*  impedances, then *reactive* loads should not worry the energy provider since there is no *real* power loss incurred?

Comment: All currents react with any impedance.

Comment: @Andyaka
But the vectors Real current and Reactive Impedance (jX) are 90 degrees apart and results in a zero when multiplied?

Comment: I was generalizing.

Comment: @Ruwan it's stil an interaction. Think about this: you have DC. Let's say it has phase 0, so it's purely real (good thing with DC is, I can claim any phase.) Now, when I attach a capacitor to that, does it interact? OF COURSE it interacts, in that the capacitor gets charged. Is this of any significance for the steady-state analysis? No, if you assume a perfect capacitor. Does it matter in the real world? OF COURSE it matters. Because, for example, the superposition principle breaks down if that constant voltage offset means that the capacitor loses capacitance (derating).

Answer (score 3):

> *REACTIVE loads should not worry the energy provider since there is no
>   REAL power loss incurred?*

The purely reactive load does not consume any net power - it takes in energy and gives that energy back cyclically.

But, current flows through the transmission line and this creates \$I^2R\$ losses in the transmission line hence, reactive loads **DO** worry energy providers.

Answer (score 0):

In industries with significant reactive loads, say inductive, you will often see steps taken to correct the current to make it closer to zero phase shift. This may be in the form of banks of capacitors.

As you have pointed out a purely reactive load takes no power.  This may suggest that the power companies should not care but it is still taking current and this current has to travel in the wiring between the customer and the power company leading to \$ I^2 \cdot R \$ losses.  This increases the size of cables required or reduces the amount of power that can be supplied to other customers.

Power companies do not like this so place a premium on the price they charge.  Non linear loads do not draw sinusoidal current so have a similar effect which has led to the requirement of PFC correction in some equipment.